# Многоязычность Интернет страницы/сайта

Tags: apache, .htaccess, php

Стало интересно как можно реализовать многоязычность Интернет страницы/сайта, "погуглил" некоторое время, но на толковое разъяснение что да как не наткнулся... Не могли бы Вы товарищи ткнуть носом в строну куда надо копать?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Нужно сделать файл, содержащий объявление констант, в которых будут строки для вывода в разных местах сайта.

Например (приводил уже где то)...

Главный файл:

```
<?php

  //объявляем константу содержащую путь до файлов языков
  define('LANGAGE_DIR', $_SERVER['DOCUMENT_ROOT']."/language/", false);
  //тоже, путь до шаблона вывода
  define('TEMPLATE_DIR', $_SERVER['DOCUMENT_ROOT']."/template/", false);

  //получаем переменную языка
  $language = $_GET['lang'];
  //не обязательно получать переменную гет-ом
  //можно брать ее откуда угодно, например - из базы данных, или из сессии

  //загружаем файл перевода
  include_once(LANGUAGE_DIR . $language . '.php');

  //загружаем файл шаблона, начинаем вывод
  include_once(TEMPLATE_DIR . 'default.php');

?>
```

Файл русского языка:

```
<?php
  define('LANG_TITLE', 'Главная страница');
  define('LANG_H1', 'Добро пожаловать!');
  define('LANG_MESSAGE1', 'Рады приветствовать вас на нашем сайте.');
?>
```

Файл английского языка:

```
<?php
  define('LANG_TITLE', 'Main page');
  define('LANG_H1', 'Welcome!');
  define('LANG_MESSAGE1', 'Welcome to our site.');
?>
```

Файл шаблона:

```
<!DOCTYPE HTML PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD HTML 4.01 Transitional//EN">
<html>
<head>
    <title><?=LANG_TITLE?></title>
</head>
<body>
    <h1><?=LANG_H1?></h1>
    <p>
        <?=LANG_MESSAGE1?>
    </p>
</body>
</html>
```

Просто нужно поместить в $language имя файла языка, для удобства без расширения. Следует еще предусмотреть вывод страницы на дефолтном языке, если в $language ничего не присвоено. Вот, такова идея. Если что не ясно, пишите! Удачного дня :)

Comment: А как сделать через отдельные текстовые файлы(.mo && .po)

Answer (score 8):

Процесс создания мультиязычности обычно делят на две части: [интернационализацию](http://ru.wikipedia.org/wiki/%D0%98%D0%BD%D1%82%D0%B5%D1%80%D0%BD%D0%B0%D1%86%D0%B8%D0%BE%D0%BD%D0%B0%D0%BB%D0%B8%D0%B7%D0%B0%D1%86%D0%B8%D1%8F) и [локализацию](http://ru.wikipedia.org/wiki/%D0%9B%D0%BE%D0%BA%D0%B0%D0%BB%D0%B8%D0%B7%D0%B0%D1%86%D0%B8%D1%8F). Оба этих процесса хорошо описаны в wikipedia.

Наиболее популярным и удобным инструментом для интернационализации, как сайтов, так и прикладных программ является [gettext](http://ru.wikipedia.org/wiki/Gettext). Для PHP так же есть соответствующее [расширение](http://php.net/gettext).

Основная идея этой библиотеки заключается в том, что для обозначения переводимой используется сама оригинальная строка, а не какие-либо специальные идентификаторы. При этом, если перевод данной строки отсутствует, то просто выводится оригинальная строка. Например, тот же шаблон ответа выше будет выглядеть так:

```
<!DOCTYPE HTML PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD HTML 4.01 Transitional//EN">
<html>
<head>
    <title><?= _('Main page') ?></title>
</head>
<body>
    <h1><?= _('Welcome!') ?></h1>
    <p>
        <?= _('Welcome to our site.') ?>
    </p>
</body>
</html>
```

Более подробно про gettext и его возможностях можно прочитать в той-же [wikipedia](http://ru.wikipedia.org/wiki/Gettext).

PS В документации к gettext говорится, что оригинальные строки должны быть на английском,  однако, в последних версиях gettext можно использовать и русские строки, при условии повсеместного использования utf-8. В этом случае, возможно, будет некоторая путаница в английской локализации, но это проблема легко решается.

Answer (score 6):

Хотелось бы дополнить, если использовать базу данных, то в списке страниц сайта, можно добавить вариант текста на нескольких языках пример таблицы :

id - идентификатор страницы в базе

name - имя на английском как псевдоним

t_ru - название на русском

t_en - название на английском

c_ru - контент на русском

c_en - контент на английском

и при необходимости грузить только нужную колонку, язык давать на выбор изначально, а сохранять его параметры в cookie, например :

```
<?php
setcookie('lang', $_POST['lang']);
?>
<form action="?set=lang" method="post">
<select name="lang">
<option value="ru">ru</option>
<option value="en">en</option>
</select>
<input type="submit" value="ok" />
</form>
<?php
$pid = $_GET['pid'];
$pref_lang = '_'.$_COOKIE['lang'];
mysql_query("SELECT t.$pref_lang, c.$pref_lang FROM pages WHERE id='$pid'");
?>
```

Примерно как то так, способов реализаций очень много, в большинстве случаях можно обойтись и без базы данных и использовать файлы. Весь смысл создания сайта на разных языках - это знать нужный для посетителя язык и выводить вариант страницы на этом языке.

А если нужно перевести надписи на кнопках, заголовки и т.д., то можно создать файл с массивами, и подключать его в начале страницы функцией require, именно ей и именно вначале, т.к. она не замедляет работу программы, как это делает include();.

пример :

```
<?php
//langpack.php
$arroflangs['button1_ru'] = 'отправить';
$arroflangs['button1_en'] = 'submit';
?>
<?php
require("./langpack.php");
$lang = '_'.$_COOKIE['lang'];
echo '<input type="button" value="'.$aroflangs['button1'.$lang]'" />';
?>
```

Сразу извиняюсь за возможные ошибки, т.к. пишу без возможности проверить.

Comment: Следует уточнить, что при использовании БД, крайне желательно кешировать результат, например, в memcache. При использовании gettext кешировать ничего не надо, т.к. данные перевода итак хранятся в разделяемой памяти.

Comment: Так оно и есть, писал на скорую руку, думаю человек сообразит.

Comment: спасибо всем за ответы!